# What does "express this equation in terms of $x$" mean (eg, for $x+y=2$)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I just had this controversial question on my maths exam and it said "express this equation in terms of $x$."

To make it simple, let’s assume that the equation was $x+y=2$.

If we are expressing the equation in terms of $x$, then would it be $y=2-x$ or $x=2-y$?

Comment: Put the $x$ in the rhs. So $y=f(x)$ as required

Comment: Better phrasing would be "Express $y$ in terms of $x$", which is to say, "Show how $y$ can be computed from an expression involving $x$." This pretty clearly conveys a goal of writing "$y=\text{$x$ stuff}$". ... I suppose "Express the *equation* in terms of $x$" is reasonably synonymous, but it seems bit sloppy to me. (If this were from an online meme or somesuch, I might actually be little concerned that an unreliable/inexperienced/mistranslated author had confused the idiom "Make $x$ the subject of the equation"; ie, write "$x=\text{$y$ stuff}$".)

Comment: Unambiguous phrasing would be "express $y$ as a function of $x$ [i.e. $y = f(x)$]".

Comment: @Blue good point. Expressing $y$ in terms of $x$ means to rewrite $y$ as a function of $x.$ On the other hand, making $x$ the subject of an equation means to rearrange the equation such that $x$ only appears on its LHS, *and* only $x$ appears on its LHS.

Answer (score 2):

Expressing an equation in terms $x$ means to express the quantity you're finding in terms of $x$, the variable.

For instance, if you're given an equation: $x + 4 = y - 1$, and asked to express it in terms of $x$;
Then $y = x + 5$, would be the required expression.

Thus for your question, $y = 2 - x$, would be the correct expression.